# ¿Por qué no marca error al sumar un int con un double y asignarlo a un int?

Tags: java, excepciones, operador

Tengo una duda con esta asignación de valor en java.

Cuando yo pongo esto:

```
double[] sumMatematicas ={50};
int suma = 0;
    
suma += sumMatematicas[0]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No arroja una excepción de "no se puede convertir implícitamente un *double* a un *int*" y me da como resultado **50**.

Pero si escribo la asignación así:

```
double[] sumMatematicas ={50};
int suma = 0;
    
suma =suma + sumMatematicas[0];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me arroja la excepción de "no se puede convertir implícitamente un *double* a un *int*".

¿A que se debe que funcione con **`+=`**?

Comment: Mira este enlace, creo que responde a la pregunta, básicamente el compilador interpreta el código como si se halla realizado un casting de tipos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/why-dont-javas-compound-assignment-operators-require-casting, sin esto, lo tendrías que hacer a mano ``suma = suma + (int) sumMatematicas[0];``

Comment: Por el valor que arroja al mostrar el resultado ``50`` se puede deducir que el compilador realizó el casteo a ``int`` la operación de adición antes de asignar el valor a la variable ``suma``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Respondo a esta pregunta basándome en el link de [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) que aparece en el enlace que compartió [@JFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/203152/jframe) en los comentarios, ya que esta pregunta me pareció interesante y no quisiera que quede abierta.**

---

La [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) para los operadores compuestos nos dice lo siguiente:

> Una expresión de asignación compuesta de la forma `E1 op = E2` es equivalente a `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, donde **T** es el tipo de **E1**, excepto que **E1** se evalúa solo una vez.

Lo que nos dice es que el compilador simplemente está casteando el resultado como vemos en el ejemplo de la misma documentación:

> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> Esto es equivalente a:
>
> ```
> short x = 3; 
> x = (short) (x + 4,6);
> ```

Que en el ejemplo que presentas tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
double[] sumMatematicas = {50};
int suma = 0;
    
suma += sumMatematicas[0];
```

Lo que equivale a:

```
double[] sumMatematicas = {50};
int suma = 0;
    
suma = (int) (suma + sumMatematicas[0]);
```

Cosa que no ocurre cuando haces:

```
suma = suma + sumMatematicas[0];
```

Porque no existe tal casteo y estas igualando un *double* a un *int* cosa que está causando el error que muestras.

> Referencia https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710685/12275542

Comment: Respuesta clara y al grano :)

Comment: Se agradece, no sabía si hacía  ``suma = suma + (int) sumMatematicas[0]`` o ``suma = (int) (suma + sumMatematicas[0])``